# В каком порядке будут вызываться конструкторы при построении объекта класса C в следующей иерархии классов

Tags: c++

В каком порядке будут вызываться конструкторы при построении объекта класса C в следующей иерархии классов:

```
class A{  };
class B: public A{  };
class D: public A{  };
class C: public D, public B{  };
int main{} {C obj;}
```

Comment: Очевидно же. adabc, или у Вас есть затруднения

Comment: порядок D и  B  не определено, так что  ничего не очевидно

Comment: Надо поискать упоминание в стандарте

Comment: А вот утверждают обратное https://stackoverflow.com/q/17328921/644688

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В приведенном фрагменте - ни в каком, потому что компилятор споткнется на

```
int main{}
```

Но если заменить фигурные скобки на круглые, то конструктор С приведет к вызову конструкторов D и B в порядке их упоминания в наследовании, а каждый из них, в свою очередь, к вызову конструктора A (наследование не виртуальное).

Т.е. ADABC.

Вот если наследование виртуальное

```
class B: virtual public A ...
class D: virtual public A ...
```

то тогда - ADBC.

Легко [проверить](https://ideone.com/W5gsPZ), написав соответствующий вывод конструкторами...

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос заковыристый.

Если добавить вывод в тела конструкторов, то выведено будет ADABC (как сказал @Harry), но это неправильный ответ.

Перед тем, как зайти в свое тело, конструктор вызывает конструкторы родителей; они не сами вызываются. Поэтому настоящий порядок: CDABA.

---

Чтобы было более наглядно, можно поменять код вот так:

```
#include <iostream>

int foo(const char *text)
{
    std::cout << text;
    return 42;
}

class A
{
  public:
    A(int)
    {
        std::cout << "Тело A()\n";
    }
};

class B : public A
{
  public:
    B(int)
        : A(foo("B() вызывает A()\n"))
    {
        std::cout << "Тело B()\n";
    }
};

class D : public A
{
  public:
    D(int)
        : A(foo("D() вызывает A()\n"))
    {
        std::cout << "Тело D()\n";
    }
};

class C : public D, public B
{
  public:
    C(int)
        : D(foo("C() вызывает D()\n")), B(foo("C() вызывает B()\n"))
    {
        std::cout << "Тело C()\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    C obj(42);
}
```

Вывод будет:

```
C() вызывает D()
D() вызывает A()
Тело A()
Тело D()
C() вызывает B()
B() вызывает A()
Тело A()
Тело B()
Тело C()
```

То есть в первую очередь выполняется список инициализации в конструкторе `C()`.

Comment: Вы описали в каком порядке создаются объекты компилятором, а вызов конструкторов будет в порядке `ADABC`.

Comment: @B1aZe Нет, еще раз, это порядок вызовов *тел* конструкторов, а не их самих. Конструкторы родителей вызываются конструктором потомка, а не сами по себе.

Comment: А объекты считаются созданными после выхода из их конструкторов, поэтому порядком создания объектов считается ADABC.

Comment: Вопрос прямой, а вот ответ юлит:)

Comment: Офигенный вопрос! Офигенный ответы! @HolyBlackCat, а подскажите, пожалуйста, где прочитать про разницу между вызовом тел конструкторов и их самих?

Comment: @S.H. Хмм. [Вот тут](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.init#class.base.init-13) есть про то, что конструктор вызывает конструкторы родителей. [Тут](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.general#7) (и в описаниях других видов инициализации) написано, что объект создается вызовом конструктора его класса (не написано, что перед ним вызываются конструкторы родителей).

Comment: Как бы выразиться... Это схоластика на уровне того, что вызов пустого конструктора и вовсе может быть опущен, а значит, никакой конструктор не вызывается...

Comment: @Harry Согласен, это большое занудство. :Р

Comment: Кстати, в приведенной вами ссылке не говорится, что конструктор производного класса *вызывает* конструктор базового. Говорится, что "базовые классы инициализируются", но нигде не говорится, что это выполняется *из* конструктора производного класса... Эдакое обезличенное выражение — оно само так делает... :)

Comment: @Harry Угу, там туманно написано. Поэтому и добавил вторую ссылку, где пишут, что объект создается вызовом только своего конструктора (значит конструкторы родителей зовутся не сами, а конструктором потомка). Вообще, это звучит менее дико, если вставить в конструкторы списки иниализации. Добавил пример.

Comment: Вообще-то в вашем примере есть только *вычисление аргумента* конструктора, но не его вызов. Так что ваше *`B() вызывает A()`* означает только, что компилятор подготовил аргумент конструктора, но это не значит, что это *вызов* из какого-то конструктора. Нет?

Comment: @Harry Не знаю, как вас еще убедить. Вот еще пример: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Wa143zEEW Конструктор родителя вызывается внутри `try` потомка.

Comment: И опять можно возразить, что это `try` охватывает и потомка, и конструктор предка... Интересно, что дискуссия привела к забавному вопросу — а что такое вообще *вызов функции*? Где он начинается, и где завершается?

Comment: @Harry Ага, всегда забавно, когда в стандарте не говорят прямо самые базовые вещи. Прошлый раз у меня такое было, когда попросили доказать, как работает `reinterpret_cast` - а там этого не оказалось. :)